# Does Intel OpenCL 2.1 support kernel C++?

Tags: opencl

I'm working on a project where I'm using OpenCL 2.1 NEO and I want to know if I can use C++ inside the kernel code. I see AMD has that feature and also OpenCL 2.1 it has C++ specs. But I'm not able to use the C++ code inside the kernel.

```
class A{
};
```

inside kernel code does not work. Does OpenCL 2.1 NEO Intel implementation support C++ code inside kernel?.

PS: I don't want to change class to struct.